# How can I make a dispenser that has unlimited arrows?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to know how to make a dispenser that can throw an infinite amount of arrows. I want to use this for my base.

Is it possible? If so how can I do it?

Comment: Please consider proof-reading your question for spelling and grammar before posting & ensure that it qualifies as a good question by reading this : .http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And watts the reason you all hate me:[

Comment: Just a tip, @chunkymonkeyman. Read our help center. Take the "[tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour)" and actually show us you have at least invested the required 5 minutes to confirm what this website is actually for, and how it works. We try to tell you what is wrong with your content, but instead of taking on the good advice, you just throw a tantrum. (Finishing the tour will also earn you a badge, which is a good way of telling if new users have even taken the effort to take our 'tutorial'.)

Answer (score 5):

The *replaceitem* command is what you're looking for. It can add items directly to chests/dispensers/etc.

```
replaceitem block [x] [y] [z] [slot] [item] [amount] [data] [dataTag]
```

x,y,z should be the position of the block. Tilde notation can be used to specify a block relative to the command block

Slot refers to the slot being filled. It needs to be in the form slot.container.x

Item refers to the item, so it should be `minecraft:arrow`

Amount refers to the number

Data and dataTag refer to extra info about the item. Arrows don't have these values- they would be necessary if, for example, you wanted to pelt people with spruce saplings.

So the command to reload the dispenser above a command block with two arrows would be:

```
replaceitem block ~ ~1 ~ slot.container.0 minecraft:arrow 2
```

Make sure this command is on the same circuit and fires when the dispenser does.

Comment: and thx for support:D

Comment: @chunkymonkeyman Next time when you ask a question, try to write like an adult. I know it's just the internet but people respond much better when you put some effort into your writing.

Comment: How??? do i do that?

Comment: Doesnt work 1111

Comment: My mistake, I forgot part of the container slot variable. Try it now.

Comment: Studoku please help im trying to write another Question but its saying the bodys wrong and crap plzzzzz Help :[

Answer (score 1):

You asked to have this for your base so I assume your playing survival.  In survival there is no way to do this without hacks or other third party materials, but there is a way to get pretty close to infinite arrows in a dispenser.  What you would want to do is have a dispenser attached to a bunch of hoppers filled with arrows like this:[image]  .The arrows in the hoppers will automatically refill the dispenser when arrows are shot.  You can have the dispensers attached in any way you want it doesn't need to be sidewards.

Comment: Any hopper beyond the first is a pretty inefficient use of resources when you could just put a chest on top of the hopper.

Answer (score 0):

You could like make the dispenser as usual but have a backup chest of arrows with redstone and stuff so it could refill when needed. Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use /clone xyz(of block) xyz(same) xyz (away) and you could put an arrow in one of the dispensers and build a Redstone clock

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post while trying to use the `replaceitem` command to put an 8 min water breathing potion in a container. I don't know if the answer above is for a different version of Minecraft or what, but the syntax of the command in the answer above does not work for the X-Box one version of Minecraft. Here's the syntax that will work for X-Box one:

`replaceitem block 3889 101 1064 slot.container 4 potion 1 20`

**Explanation:**

`replaceitem`: the name of the command

`block`: part of the `replaceitem` command syntax

`3889`: the `x` coordinate of the container to put the item in

`101`: the `y` coordinate of the container to put the item in

`1064`: the `z` coordinate of the container to put the item in

`slot.container`: stating that you are wanting to put an item in a slot within the container

`4`: the slot number of the container you want to put the item in

`potion`: the type of item you are wanting to put in the slot (types are listed in the `namespaceid` column on the page [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_data_values))

`1`: the number of items to put in the slot

`20`: the [data value](https://www.digminecraft.com/lists/item_id_list_xbox_one.php) of the item you want to put in the slot

to use this yourself you would have to come up with the `x y z` coordinates of the container in your game, the slot number within the container you want to put the item in as well as the data value of the specific item you want to place.

Hope this helps.