# Minecraft 1.8.9 how do you give yourself -1 of an item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to have a dispenser able to dispense an infinite amount of Splash Potion of Harming II, and from what I can see the best way is getting a -1 stack of the item, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Did you try `/replaceitem`? If that doesn't work, you'll have to edit an item entity with `/entitydata`. I also want to note that this is a bug and as far as I know all sources of negative stacks are fixed in the current version.

Comment: I don't see how this question is unclear, It's basically "How can I make a dispenser dispense an infinite amount of Splash Potions of Harming II?".

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about giving yourself -1 of an item but to get an infinite dispenser you can use the *replaceitem* command. It is entered like

> replaceitem block [x] [y] [z] [slot] [item] [amount] [data] [dataTag]

If you need more help you should just be able to make a quick google search for *replace item command in Minecraft in 1.8.9* or *Infinite dispenser in 1.8.9*

Otherwise this post is good:
[How can I make a dispenser that has unlimited arrows?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257624/how-can-i-make-a-dispenser-that-has-unlimited-arrows)